# Angular Pass Multiple Authorization Headers

Tags: angular, header, mailchimp

I was trying to pass an additional authorization header(Basic Auth) to a Mailchimp integration I did for my system but my user Authorization token that I set globally is interfering! is there a way to pass the Mailchimp header to a specific API only? Any help is appreciated!

Here is my user token interceptor

```
  constructor(private accountService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

let currentUser!: User;

this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => currentUser = user);

if(currentUser){

  request = request.clone({setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
  }})
}

return next.handle(request);

  }
```

Comment: You could add an interaceptor, which alters the request in case of mailchimp uri. If the global token is also set in interceptor, which I assume, just make sure the global one runs beforehand.

Comment: i am a beginner so beg with me... this is my intercept for user authorization 
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

let currentUser!: User;

this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => currentUser = user);

if(currentUser){

  request = request.clone({setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
  }})
}

return next.handle(request);

  } can you show me how to pull off the comment you just shared

Comment: Kindly add the code into your question. I wouldn't change your current interceptor. You can chain interceptors. Chain another one for mailchimp, which runs after the first one. The request param contains an field showing the request url. You can check it and in case it is the mailchimp url overwrite the header.

Comment: i did add the code in my question